# Postfix, Edited sasl_passwd and now the relay fails authentication

Tags: postfix

So I'm running Postfix 3.1.0 on a work server. It's relaying emails to AWS SES and I just updated the access key. I removed the previous value in `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and then ran `postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and email was failing authentication. Then I `systemctl` restart postfix and still no auth success. The only information I can find is regarding the postmap command and that should JUST WORK.

Like I said I logged onto a working system.. created a new access key in IAM. Put that new into into /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd and thats the only change I've made. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The question is that the work - postfix server have any related relay before server.
Like, Ironport or proxy for example.
If yes, you need firewall accesses or update postfix with sample below.

Also dont forget to use postconf command to give postfix the latest config update
DESCRIPTION
By default, the postconf(1) command displays the values of main.cf con‐
figuration parameters, and warns  about  possible  mis-typed  parameter
names  (Postfix  2.9 and later).  It can also change main.cf configura‐
tion parameter values, or display other configuration information about
the Postfix mail system.

#DOMAIN.any mail server config

#relayhost = [smtp.relaydomain.ext]:587
#smtp_use_tls=yes
#smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
#smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_passwords
#smtp_sasl_security_options =

Comment: I did not know about the postconf command.. thanks for that. I did end up figuring this out and the cause was a missing [ in sasl_passwd file. I had to wake up a co-worker to find this and I glossed over it for an hour.